# Haskell unexpected type in class declaration

Tags: class, haskell

I try to implement a function (Tree a) -> (Tree a) -> (Tree a). The function should sum the node values and return a tree with the sums. Unfortunatley i got the following error message:

Aufgabe10.hs:4:11:
    Unexpected type ‘Tree a’
    In the class declaration for ‘+’
    A class declaration should have form
      class + a b c where ...

This is my code:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
    |Empty

class (+) (Tree a) where
    (+) :: (Tree a) (Tree a) -> (Tree a)

instance (Num a) => (+) (Tree a) (Tree a) where
    (+) (Node a1 b1 c1)  (Node a2 b2 c2) = (Node (a1+a2) ((+) b1 b2)  ((+) c1 c2)) 
    (+) Empty (Node a b c) = (Node a b c) 
    (+) (Node a b c) Empty = (Node a b c)
```

---

Ok i changed now the class to Plus and named the function plus, cause i don't want to implement all the numb functions. This is the new code:

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
    |Empty

class Plus a where
    plus:: (Tree a)  -> (Tree a)  -> (Tree a) 

instance (Num a) => Plus (Tree a) where
    Plus (Node a1 b1 c1)  (Node a2 b2 c2) = (Node (a1+a2) (Plus b1 b2)  (Plus c1 c2)) 
    Plus Empty (Node a b c) = (Node a b c) 
    Plus (Node a b c) Empty = (Node a b c)
```

I get the following errors:

Aufgabe10.hs:8:9:
    Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declarations
      Plus (Node a1 b1 c1) (Node a2 b2 c2)
        = (Node (a1 + a2) (Plus b1 b2) (Plus c1 c2))

Aufgabe10.hs:9:9:
    Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declarations
      Plus Empty (Node a b c) = (Node a b c)

Aufgabe10.hs:10:9:
    Pattern bindings (except simple variables) not allowed in instance declarations
      Plus (Node a b c) Empty = (Node a b c)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by writing `class (+) (Tree a) where`?

Comment: My understanding of your homework is that you have to write a `Num` instance for `Tree a`. You probably do not want to write a class declaration, here. However, if my guess is correct, you will also have to implement the other methods required for a `Num` instance declaration; see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:7

Comment: `(Tree a) (Tree a) -> ...` should also be `(Tree a) -> (Tree a) -> ...`

Comment: And `instance (Num a) => (+) (Tree a) (Tree a)` should probably be `instance (Num a) => Num (Tree a)`.

Comment: The exercise is just to implement a function (+)::(Tree a)->(Tree a) -> (Tree a)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [What are typeclasses?](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html#typeclasses.whatarethey): there you gonna notice that typeclasses declaration takes:

1. the typeclass name;
2. a type variable.

Hence, your declaration should start as

```
class (+) a where
```

not

```
class (+) (Tree a) where
```

although I would prefer

```
class Plus a where
```

That solves the first of your problems. :)

---

Answering your updated version...

Do you see the difference between `Plus` and `plus`? Yes, one is capitalized and the other is not. Do you know what it means in Haskell?

`Plus`, as every capitalized word in Haskell, refers to **types** (in this case, *type class* called `Plus`).

By the other hand, functions must be always lowercase — and that is why you defined `plus :: (Tree a)  -> (Tree a)  -> (Tree a)` in lowercase.

Have you already gotten your problem?

Instead of

```
instance (Num a) => Plus (Tree a) where
    Plus (Node a1 b1 c1)  (Node a2 b2 c2) = (Node (a1+a2) (Plus b1 b2)  (Plus c1 c2)) 
    Plus Empty (Node a b c) = (Node a b c) 
    Plus (Node a b c) Empty = (Node a b c)
```

you should have written

```
instance (Num a) => Plus (Tree a) where
    plus (Node a1 b1 c1)  (Node a2 b2 c2) = (Node (a1+a2) (Plus b1 b2)  (Plus c1 c2)) 
    plus Empty (Node a b c) = (Node a b c) 
    plus (Node a b c) Empty = (Node a b c)
```

because you are defining the behaviour of the function `plus` when `Tree` is an instance of `Plus`. Got it? :)